# Using type casting and generics in java

Tags: java, generics

I have  this following interface :

```
    public interface FruitDetails {
            public String getFruitName(); 
    }
```

And few Classes that implements the above interface :

```
    public class Banana implements FruitDetails{

        private int index;
            public Banana(int i) {
                index = i;
        }

        @Override
        public String getFruitName() {
            return "Banana Fruit " + index;
        }

    }
```

and

```
    public class Apple implements FruitDetails{

        private int index;
            public Apple(int i) {
                index = i;
        }

        @Override
        public String getFruitName() {
            return "AppleFruit " + index;
        }

    }
```

I have a function that prints the details of the fruits :

```
    static void getFruitDetails(List<FruitDetails> fruits) {
            for (FruitDetails fruitDetails : fruits) {
                    System.out.println(fruitDetails.getFruitName());
            }
    }
```

Now i will create a list of Bananas :

```
  List<Banana> bananaList = new ArrayList<Banana>();
  bananaList.add(new Banana(0));
  bananaList.add(new Banana(1));
```

Now i want to print Details of bananas in the above list using getFruitDetails.

Issue is if try to call

```
  getFruitDetails(bananaList);
```

I am getting compile time error :

```
The method getFruitDetails(List<FruitDetails>) in the type MainClass is not applicable for the arguments (List<Banana>)
```

How I can resolve this.

And also need to define getFruitDetails such that i should be able to print details of banana list or apple list

Comment: Maybe it's my OCD but it would be great if the interface was called Fruit instead of FruitDetails :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To accept all implementing classes of FruitDetails as the argument for getFruitDetails, you need to use the type `List<? extends FruitDetails>`:

```
static void getFruitDetails(List<? extends FruitDetails> fruits) {
        for (FruitDetails fruitDetails : fruits) {
                System.out.println(fruitDetails.getFruitName());
        }
}
```

As a side effect this makes the List `fruits` in `getFruitDetails` effectively read only for the reason that *JB Nizet* describes in the comments.

Comment: Just to explain (once again): If a List<Banana> was a List<Fruit>, you could add an Apple to the list, and it would thus break the type-safety of the list.

Comment: But I have FruitDetails as an interface.

Comment: this is correct. Sorry i was under the impression that as FruitDetails was a **interface**, expression **"? extends FruitDetails"** should be **"? implements FruitDetails"** which was giving error. Also can i know how this works.

Comment: @Pavan: in generics, type bounds are expressed using `extends` and `super` regardless of whether the type happens to be a class or interface (or, even a type variable, in which case we don't know whether it is a class or interface)

Answer (score 1):

This is because you can not assign `List<Banana>` to `List<FruitDetails>`. Try changing the code to

```
static void getFruitDetails(List<? extends FruitDetails> fruits) {
        for (FruitDetails fruitDetails : fruits) {
                System.out.println(fruitDetails.getFruitName());
        }
}
```

you should read about [generics subtyping](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/subtype.html) to understand this.

Comment: Again FruitDetails is not a Baseclass. Its an interface